# IBaction over different views

Tags: xcode, view, ibaction

I'm learning to create apps for iphone with xcode by doing. I've doing this for about 2-3 weeks so I'm totally new to this. Right now i've decided to make a counter that contains different kind of counters, each counter in it own view. Navigation between them is done through a tab bar.

I have 4 views and the last view is supposed to contain reset buttons to each counter in the other 3 views.

Is it possible? In that case, could you please point me in the right direction?

Right now I'm using this to reset the counter from the same view

```
-(IBAction)Reset:(id)sender{
    counter = 0;
    count.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", counter];
```

Can I do the above from let's say view 4 in order to reset the counter in view 1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

John, I doubt you should be looking at NSUserDefaults. And if this is your first assignment, your teacher will frown on it.

Honestly, I think the above is a bad habit to get used to and bypass good MVC basics. Since you seem new to this, you should focus on good MVC basics: The View controller on top of the pyramid controls its views. In this case, you have one more layer where the UITabBarController controls a bunch of viewControllers (tabs) and these ViewControllers control their views.

You move between these viewControllers (tabs) by using the "viewControllers" property of UITabBarController.

Each one of those viewControllers (UIViewController subclass) should be created in IB and in code and then attached to the UITabBarController. You should then change the class of these viewcontrollers in IB identity inspector to your corresponding UIViewController subclass name.

Then you add your label and actions to the appropriate view controllers and hook them to the corresponding viewcontrollers in your code.

and you can use [self.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1] from your viewController 4 to reset the counter on view 1.

There are no code shortcuts here. Learn proper MVC or it will bite you later.

Hope this helps

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it is possible. But your question is not that much clarity. As per my understanding fourth view having a button called refresh and when we click on button remaining 3 views should be replaced with content which is having starting onwards.

by simple way, when you click on `Refresh button` in fourth view, `release` the `UITabbarController` and add again.

Or else Need to call Refresh View in all 3 screens w.r.t `UITbabarController Delegate` method.

Comment: let me clarify. As it is counters I'm trying to make, i have in each view a textfield that shows a number that counts each button tapped in that view. for exmaple I would like to reset the counter in view 1 to zero once the reset button in the 4th view is tapped. if it's in the same view i use -(IBAction)Reset:(id)sender{
    counter = 0;
    count.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", counter]; but how can i reset that counter from the 4th view?

Comment: Ok. for each view while changing Tabbar, it will call "- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated" method. while click on refresh button, just save flag in NSUserdefaults and provide conditions in view will appear.

Comment: hi madhu, thanks for your reply. im totally new to this, still experimenting with the basics.. could you please tell me how to do that?

Answer (score -1):

```
    - (void)refresh
    {
   NSLog(@"Refresh Data");
   [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"data_refresh"];
   [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
   }
```

//Add this method in all 3 views

```
   - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
      {
       [super viewWillAppear:animated];

           if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"data_refresh"] && [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"data_refresh"] boolValue]) {
            count.text = @"0"; // Here you can modify the data as you expected.
         [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removeObjectForKey:@"data_refresh"];
         [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
       }
     }
```

Comment: if s/he is new to ObjC, I doubt, he should be using NSUSerDefaults to bypass good MVC basics!

Comment: is this some kind of automatic reset? i want to be able to push a button in order to reset. that button is gonna be on the 4th view and the counter that is going to affected is in view 1.